# why I can't insert this JavaScript line into the WSO2 ESB script mediator? It is cause of a syntext error

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am going crazy trying inserting this JavaScript line into the WSO2 ESB **script** mediator:

```
response.forecast = response.forecast.map( s => Object.values(s)[0] );
```

after the insertion of this line into my script, trying to save I obtain an error message into the Developer Studio. It is finding a syntax error related to this line (performing the same JavaScript into my browser it works fine and I have no error. I tried to save it anyway and to deploy as Carbon application but now I obtain error in the Carbon console:

```
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: syntax error (<Unknown Source>#217)
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.compile(RhinoScriptEngine.java:341)
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.compile(RhinoScriptEngine.java:323)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.initInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:399)
        ... 32 more
```

What could be the problem? Why this line is creating problem only into the WSO2 ESB script mediator?

Maybe have I to escape some character or something like this? How can I try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

your JS will be inline inside script mediator :

```
<script language="js">                          
    response.forecast = response.forecast.map( s => Object.values(s)[0] );
</script>
```

guess the ">" is the problem, you can escape it using `&gt;` or you can use a CDATA section :

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[                         
    response.forecast = response.forecast.map( s => Object.values(s)[0] );
]]></script>
```